# Meteor WhatsApp clone tutorial will not construct ChatsCtrl inside chats.controller.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

After several hours of banging my head attempting to find the error, I've come to realize that I lack the fundamental understanding of `angular-ecmascript` to be able to resolve my own problem. Either that, or I'm loosing my head.

Following the *Meteor WhatsApp Clone* tutorial [here](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/layout), I can't seem to get past step 1.14, where `client/templates/chats.html` renders the data inside `client/scripts/controllers/chats.controller.js`.

I've followed the tutorial word-by-word, and after several testing it seems that the class `ChatsCtrl` inside `chats.controller.js` is not being created (?).

I have **not modified anything** other than add the `console.log()` for presentation purposes. Here are snippets of all related classes:

**app.js**

```
...

// Modules
import ChatsCtrl from '../controllers/chats.controller';
import RoutesConfig from '../routes';

...

console.log("We are inside app.js");

new Loader(App)
  .load(ChatsCtrl)
  .load(RoutesConfig);

...
```

**routes.js**

```
import { Config } from 'angular-ecmascript/module-helpers';

export default class RoutesConfig extends Config {
  configure() {
    console.log("We are inside RoutesConfig in routes.js");

...
```

**chats.controller.js**

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import { Controller } from 'angular-ecmascript/module-helpers';

console.log("We are inside chats.controller.js");

export default class ChatsCtrl extends Controller {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    console.log("We are inside ChatsCtrl in chats.controller.js");

...
```

And here is our console output:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHMqR.png)

```
We are inside chats.controller.js          chats.controller.js:4
We are inside app.js                       app.js:23
We are inside RoutesConfig in routes.js    routes.js:5
```

As you can see, `We are inside ChatsCtrl in chats.controller.js` is never executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I never added in here that perhaps I should: after linking this to the devs at the time, it seems that there was a bug on the tutorial that was fixed. This should be no longer an issue with `Meteor.js`.